# SQLiteOpenHelper - Cannot access disposed object

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, sqliteopenhelper

I have a my `SQLiteOpenHelper` class, which is written as a singleton. I should note that I am not doing this in Java, I am using Xamarin.Android C# to write this.

Here's a snippet from that class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper : SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static readonly string TAG = typeof(DatabaseHelper).FullName;

    private static readonly string _databaseName = "istockdb";

    private static readonly int _databaseVersion = 32;

    private static DatabaseHelper _instance;

    private Context _context;

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) : base(context, _databaseName, null, _databaseVersion)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public static DatabaseHelper Instance(Context context)
    {
        // *** Use the application context, which will ensure that ***
        // *** the Activity's context is not accidentally leaked ***
        return _instance ?? (_instance = new DatabaseHelper(context.ApplicationContext));
    }

}
```

So I have my `DatabaseHelper` that is a singleton and is used like this within Activities and Services:

Service:

```
[Service(Name=Text.MobileBackgroundHbService, Enabled = true, Exported = true), IntentFilter(new []{Intents.SyncHeartbeats})]
public class BGHeartbeatService : BaseIntentService
{
    public BGHeartbeatService()
    {
        this._database = DatabaseHelper.Instance(Application.Context);
    }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        if (this._database == null)
            this._database = DatabaseHelper.Instance(Application.Context);

        if (intent.Action.Equals(Intents.SyncHeartbeats)) SyncHeartbeatRecords();

        var broadcastIntent = new Intent(Intents.MobileRefresh);
        SendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

}
```

Activity, actually a `BaseActivity` which all Activities inherit from:

```
[Activity(Label = "BaseActivity")]
public abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to the current context.
    /// </summary>
    protected Context _context { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// "Tag" used for Log functionallity.
    /// </summary>
    protected string _tag { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reference To <see cref="RemoteSyncServiceConnection"/>
    /// </summary>
    protected RemoteSyncServiceConnection _service_connection;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reference To The Current SessionState.
    /// </summary>
    protected SessionState _session_state;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reference To <see cref="SyncReceiver"/>
    /// </summary>
    protected SyncReceiver _sync_receiver;

    /// <summary>
    /// Base FloatingActionButton.
    /// </summary>
    protected FloatingActionButton _base_fab;

    /// <summary>
    /// Is the Fab Menu Shown / Hid.
    /// </summary>
    protected static bool _is_fab_open;

    protected IConnection _printer_connection;

    protected string _printer_address;

    protected bool _service_required;

    protected bool _receiver_required;

    protected MediaPlayer _media_player;

    protected DatabaseHelper _database;

    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="IntentFilter"/> for the <see cref="SyncReceiver"/>
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly string[] _intent_filters =
    {
        Intents.AlarmCompleteOrders,
        Intents.AlarmHeartbeats,
        Intents.AlarmPkas,
        Intents.AlarmTrackingScans,
        Intents.MobileRefresh
    };

    #region Lifecycle Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Application Lifecycle Method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="savedInstanceState"></param>
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // *** Initialize Xamarin.Essentials ***
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        // *** Initialize the DatabaseHelper ***
        if(this._database == null)
            this._database = DatabaseHelper.Instance(this.ApplicationContext);
    }

}
```

The `DatabaseHelper` instance is being disposed of frequently causing either services, or activities to try and access the disposed `_database` object.

How is this being disposed of and why?

I thought making the `_instance` static within the `DatabaseHelper` as well as making the constructor private and forcing the use of the `DatabaseHelper.Instance` method would keep a single instance of the `DatabaseHelper` that wouldn't be disposed of between activities and services?

Am I misunderstanding this?

EDIT logcat output from try/catch blocks showing the exception being thrown. The `SaveHeartbeat` method exists in the base activity.:

```
protected void SaveHeartbeat(DateTime time, string sourceActivity, [CallerMemberName] string sourceEvent = "")
        {
            try
            {
                var heartbeat = new SmartWarehouse.Shared.Models.Heartbeat(sourceActivity,
                                                                            sourceEvent,
                                                                            this._session_state.CurrentSession.ROWID.ToString());

                this._database.InsertHeartbeat(heartbeat);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO: Document Exception
                Util.Tools.Bark(e);
            }
        }
```

[image: Exception Logcat]

EDIT 2 DatabaseHelper.InsertHeartbeat():

```
/// <summary>
/// Inserts a Heartbeat record into local DB.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="heartbeat"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public long InsertHeartbeat(Heartbeat heartbeat)
{
    if (heartbeat == null) return -2L;
    using (var db = this.WritableDatabase)
    {
        var id = -3L;
        db.BeginTransactionNonExclusive();
        try
        {
            var cv = GetContentValues(heartbeat);
            id = db.Insert(DatabaseSchema.Heartbeat.TableName, null, cv);
            db.SetTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: Document Exception
            Util.Tools.Bark(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            db.EndTransaction();
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

Alright so my theory is that when I access the `db` object in the `using()` statement it is disposing of the database that the `DatabaseHelper` object uses. Also noticed that I'm not using `db.InsertOrThrow()` method which I should be.. Gonna do some re-working on my `DatabaseHelper` class to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence that the DatabaseHelper instance is being disposed?

Comment: One Second I'll post some logcat output

Comment: Really not sure what's going on here. I will point out, though, that it appears to be the  SQLiteDatabase that is being disposed, not the DatabaseHelper.  If that DatabaseHelper is getting disposed, my world makes no sense anymore.

Comment: DAMN! I think you're right on the money actually, I'm gonna post an edit to clarify. But I need to rework my helper methods not to dispose of the database I bet thats causing the probs.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Thanks for your help! pretty sure that I'm disposing of the SQLiteDatabase object due to the way I access it in my helper methods with the using() statement. Will update if this resolves the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my singleton instance of the `DatbaseHelper` was not being disposed of.

Actually what was happening is I was disposing of the `SQLiteDatabase` object that was being used by the `DatbaseHelper` from within the helper methods.

All I had to do to actually resolve the issue was change:

```
/// <summary>
/// Inserts a Heartbeat record into local DB.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="heartbeat"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public long InsertHeartbeat(Heartbeat heartbeat)
{
    if (heartbeat == null) return -2L;
    // This using() statement is causing the disposal
    using (var db = this.WritableDatabase)
    {
        var id = -3L;
        db.BeginTransactionNonExclusive();
        try
        {
            var cv = GetContentValues(heartbeat);
            id = db.Insert(DatabaseSchema.Heartbeat.TableName, null, cv);
            db.SetTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: Document Exception
            Util.Tools.Bark(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            db.EndTransaction();
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

TO:

```
/// <summary>
/// Inserts a Heartbeat record into local DB.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="heartbeat"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public long InsertHeartbeat(Heartbeat heartbeat)
{
    if (heartbeat == null) return -2L;

    // This is no longer initialized in a using() statement
    var db = this.WritableDatabase;

        var id = -3L;
        db.BeginTransactionNonExclusive();
        try
        {
            var cv = GetContentValues(heartbeat);
            id = db.Insert(DatabaseSchema.Heartbeat.TableName, null, cv);
            db.SetTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: Document Exception
            Util.Tools.Bark(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            db.EndTransaction();
        }
        return id;

}
```

SUMMARY:

By initializing my `SQLiteDatabase db` object inside of `using()` statements inside of my helper methods I was disposing of the `SQLiteDatabase` that my `DatabaseHelper` needed.